# Why can I not catch a Queue.Empty exception from a multiprocessing Queue?

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7

I'm trying to catch a Queue.Empty exception that is raised if a multiprocessing.Queue is empty. The following does not work:

```
import multiprocessing
f = multiprocessing.Queue()
try:
      f.get(True,0.1)
except Queue.Empty:
      print 'foo'
```

This gives me a name error: NameError: name 'Queue' is not defined

replacing Queue.Empty with multiprocessing.Queue.Empty does not help either. In this case it gives me a "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Empty'" exception.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `Empty` exception you're looking for isn't available directly in the `multiprocessing` module, because `multiprocessing` borrows it from the `queue` module (which used to be named `Queue` in Python 2). To make your code work, just do an `import queue` at the top:

Try this:

```
import multiprocessing
import queue # or Queue in Python 2

f = multiprocessing.Queue()
try:
    f.get(True,0.1)
except queue.Empty: # queue here refers to the module, not a class
    print('foo')
```

Comment: [`multiprocessing` should (and does) use `isinstance(exception, Queue.Empty)`](http://ideone.com/iHpNoJ) (Queue is a module) because multiprocessing emulates threading api that often used with Queue.Queue and exceptions are part of the api.

Comment: Oh, I see. `multiprocessing.queues.Empty` is `Queue.Empty` (just imported there for `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` to use). I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Blckknght @J.F. Sebastian Thanks this works, but I'm not sure why. By importing multiprocessing have I not imported all the modules that multiprocessing imports? So why do I need the line `import Queue` ? Also how do you figure that out? There was nothing about needing to import Queue from the documentation of multiprocessing.

Comment: @Alexander: a module (e.g., `multiprocessing`) can use objects (e.g., raise exceptions) that are defined in other modules (in this case `Empty` name is defined in `Queue` module). The docs say that `multiprocessing.Queue` is a near clone of `Queue.Queue`. It means you should expect the same api: available methods, their arguments, exceptions raised are the same unless specified otherwise. And `Queue.Queue` documents when it raises `Queue.Empty`.

Answer (score 21):

Blckknght's answer from back in 2012 is still correct, however using Python 3.7.1 I discovered that you have to use queue.Empty as the name of the exception to catch (Note the lowercase 'q' in 'queue'.)

So, to recap:

```
import queue

# Create a queue
queuevarname = queue.Queue(5) # size of queue is unimportant

while some_condition_is_true:
    try:
        # attempt to read queue in a way that the exception could be thrown
        queuedObject = queuevarname.get(False)

        ...
    except queue.Empty:
        # Do whatever you want here, e.g. pass so
        # your loop can continue, or exit the program, or...
```