# How to import and catch module-specific exceptions in Python?

Tags: python, exception

Python modules often have their own exceptions. I often find myself wanting to import those exceptions to be able to properly catch them (properly as in not just cacthing `Exception` and hoping for the best).

However, I often find myself spending time to figure out exactly where in a module the exceptions are located, or if they're imported from another module, etc. I'm curious if there's a general way to find this out, i.e. given `SomeModulespecificException` is there a simple way to figure out how to import it?

Here's an example from the multiprocessing module:

```
import multiprocessing
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
q.get_nowait()
```

The above code raises an `Empty` Exception. In this case, I found out from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941562/why-can-i-not-catch-a-queue-empty-exception-from-a-multiprocessing-queue#answer-13941865) that the exception is imported from the `Queue` module, so in this particular case, you need `from Queue import Empty` to import the exception.

Is there an easy way to figure this out in the general case?

Comment: I usually catch `Exception as e` while developing and then `print(type(e))` to see what I should actually be catching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python When I catch an exception, how do I get the type, file, and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278705/python-when-i-catch-an-exception-how-do-i-get-the-type-file-and-line-number)

Comment: @Georgy no, not really. The issue here wasn't general exception catching, but, given that module X throws and error specific to that module, how does one figure out where to import the given exception from X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I usually do it:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
... q = multiprocessing.Queue()
... q.get_nowait()
... 
... 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<...snip...>
>>> import sys
>>> err = sys.last_value
>>> err.__module__
'queue'
>>> from queue import Empty
>>> isinstance(err, Empty)
True
```

There is no foolproof way that works for all modules in the generic case, because they don't usually know (or care) about all their dependencies exception hierarchy. An exception in 3rd party code would just bubble up the stack, and there is generally no point to catch it unless one can actually do something to handle it and continue. Good projects will usually document the exception hierarchy clearly in their API guide.